# Download and Upload Multiple Images and Videos Like WhatsApp application

Tags: android, download, upload, adapter

I am developing an Android Chatting application in that I want to implement Upload and Download multiple images asynchronously like WhatsApp.

From activity I am able to send single image using **Service** and **Receiver**, but in Adapter how to manage?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not now for multiple media.

Comment: Did u find any solution ?